# How to get a grid 500m x 500m on map composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer, grids-graticules, mapping

I need to make a map on map composer, with a grid layed on it which is 500m x 500m. however the only way I could find of doing this was by adding a grid to my map, found within item properties.

This works fine however to  get a grid of 500m, I have had to set the 'Interval' to

> x = 0.009200000000
>   Y = 0.009200000000

with the 'Interval units' set ot 'Map units' which in this case is 'Meters'.

As you can see from the image below my grid 'By eye' is ~500m.
[image]

Is there an accurate way to produce a grid to fit a required distance accuratly?.

I am usign QGIS V3.4

Comment: Are you sure the CRS you're using is in meters? Otherwise, the `x` and `y` intervals should be `500` if you're selecting map units.

Comment: Yes I have tried both is a CRS In degree and Meters and both I am finding will not give me a 500m grid, just by inputing 500m for both X-Axis and Y-Axis

Comment: please add which CRS you are using, I;ve just tested and in the UK (27700) it works as expected

Comment: I am using the EPSG (27700) As well